# Normal running temperature of a FX-8320E

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-cooler

My FX-8320E has small liquid cooling which might be insufficient.

The CPU stays at 60+°C even when idle.

Is this temperature dangerously high ?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this post was closed. It's badly worded, but it's clear that it asks if 60+°C is normal idle temp for the FX-8320E. This is a hardware question that's on-subject here.

Comment: @harrymc I'd say it doesn't even ask a question. Could be formulated a lot better, feel free to word better and I'll vote to reopen as well.

Comment: @Destroy666: Done. With having posters from all over the world, I think we should be more lenient with badly-worded posts that can still be understood.

Answer (score 0):

The
[FX-8320E General Specifications page](https://www.amd.com/en/product/1446)
contains:

```
Max. Operating Temperature (Tjmax)
70.5°C
```

The
[AMD FX-8320 Black Edition Specifications page](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-8320)
recommends:

```
Max. Operating Temperature (Tjmax)
61.1°C
```

If your model is not the Black Edition, then your temperature reading
is high, but still within operating range.
You should rather keep a careful eye on the temperature when
it's under load.